# 'border_color' custom tkinter not working properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, project, customtkinter, tkinter-layout

I am using `border_color` on a custom tkinter frame and it is not working properly. Here is a picture of how it looks:

[image: Image of the problem]

I want the border colour to be around the whole frame but it is not doing so.

Here is my code:

```py
        #this function displays message
        def message(self):
            #function displays important message to user
            self.message_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.parent.functions_frame, border_width=3, border_color="white")
            self.message_frame.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.05)

            self.message_title = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.message_frame,
                text="Important:",
                font=ctk.CTkFont(size=17, weight="bold")
            )
            self.message_title.grid(row=0,column=0)

            self.messages = ctk.CTkLabel(self.message_frame, text="""*Where you can enter a mark you can also update a
mark for the same student by entering a different one""", text_color="red")
            self.messages.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add padding between the edge of the `ctk.Frame` to the `ctk.Label`s inside it, so the labels are on the border. You can add padding using `padx` and `pady` for your widgets inside the frame.

##### Here is an example:

```
def message():
    #function displays important message to user
    message_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(root, border_width=3, border_color="white")
    padding = 4 # you can change it as you like
    message_frame.place(relx=0.07, rely=0.05)

    message_title = ctk.CTkLabel(
        message_frame,
        text="Important:",
        font=ctk.CTkFont(size=17, weight="bold")
    )
    message_title.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=padding)

    messages = ctk.CTkLabel(message_frame, text="""*Where you can enter a mark you can also update a
mark for the same student by entering a different one""", text_color="red")
    messages.grid(row=1,column=0, pady=padding, padx=padding)
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I implemented what you said and it works. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Have I done it now? I’m new to this

Comment: Yes. As a new user, you might want to read *[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)*. Welcome to Stack Overflow!